# Django / Python, Make database save function re-usable (so that it takes modelname and appname from strings), using contenttypes or some other method?

Tags: python, django, content-type, code-reuse

I want to make some functions that are re-usable by any model so that I can specify the appname and model in string format and then use this to import that model and make calls to it such as creating database fields, updating, deleting, etc...

I had thought I could do this using contenttypes in Django but am trying this, as below and am getting the error message "'ContentType' object is not callable":

```
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
    instancemodelname = ContentType.objects.get(app_label="myappname", model="mymodelname")

    b = instancemodelname(account_username='testtestest')
    b.save()
    >>>>'ContentType' object is not callable
```

I would appreciate any advice on the proper way to do this, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will work:

```
instancemodelname = ContentType.objects.get(app_label="myappname", model="mymodelname")
b = instancemodelname.model_class()(account_username='testtestest')
b.save()
```

That said I am not entirely convinced that contenttypes is the best way to achieve what you want.

Comment: thanks, I'm not sure it is the best way either... I would appreciate tips on any other methods as this would be useful as well for a context outside of Django in the future

Comment: your answer is spot on so I've already chosen it as correct, however would be interested as to alternate ways to do this so that I can look into it further to better improve my knowledge of this sort of thing

Comment: One way to go about this would be to write a function(s) to import the model at runtime and then create instances etc. Save the function in an utility suite.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the ContentType model. There's a function for exactly this use case that doesn't genereate a database hit:

```
from django.db.models import get_model
mymodel = get_model("myappname", "mymodelname")
b = mymodel(account_username='testtestest')
b.save()
```